# How to create a table in SQL Server with RevoScaleR?

Tags: r, sql-server, machine-learning

I'd like to create a table in my SQL Server database running on a local instance and populate it with mine predicitve model written in R; to which aim I call these lines of R script:

```
predictionSql = RxSqlServerData(table = "Logit_FPD60_ZIP", connectionString = connStr)
predict_logit = rxPredict(logit_model, input_data, outData = predictionSql)
```

...which returns:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed for user
>   'my server'.

I can establish a connection and preview data from the server.

I've tried:

1. Set SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode in my SQL Server
   Security properties and restart both the service and Lunchpad.
2. Create a generic SQL Server Connector

which is:

> [ODBC] DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0 DATABASE=Predict
>   WSID=NB-IT-JIRAK APP=Operační systém Microsoft® Windows®
>   Trusted_Connection=Yes SERVER=NB-IT-JIRAK\SJ Description=Generic SQL
>   Connector

I'm using this connection string in R:

```
connStr <- paste("Driver=SQL Server; Server=", "NB-IT-JIRAK\\SJ",
                 ";Database=", "Predict", ";Trusted_Connection=true", sep = "");
```

What am I missing? New to R, help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you include the correct login information in the connection string?

Comment: The problem was, I have not setted up db_dataread and ddl permissions to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change connection string to `sa` if it is a test machine or a use a privileged account:

```
connection_string <- sprintf("Driver=SQL Server;Server=%s;Database=%s;Uid=sa;Pwd=mypass", server, db_name)
commented: --> connection_string <- sprintf("Driver=SQL Server;Server=%s;Database=%s;Trusted_Connection=Yes", server, db_name)
```